# UWP NumberBox custom value template

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to have a number-box like the image below, where the user can always see the maximum value [in my project the minimum value is always 1 and does not need to be shown], Is this possible? How should I do this?

[image]

```
<muxc:NumberBox Name="NumberBoxSpinButtonPlacementExample"
                Header="Page"
                Value="12" Minimum="1" Maximum="128"
                SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact"
                SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10"
                Width="100"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

I found the following code in this links [ [WinUI NumberBox Control](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2020/winui-numberbox-control) ], I think I should use this method, maybe not, I do not know

```
private DecimalFormatter DutchDecimalFormatter { get; } = 
    new DecimalFormatter(new[] { "nl-NL" }, "NL") 
{
        IsGrouped = true,
        FractionDigits = 2,
        NumberRounder = new IncrementNumberRounder {
            Increment = 0.01,
            RoundingAlgorithm = RoundingAlgorithm.RoundHalfUp,
        }
};
```

---

**Result :**

```
<RelativePanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <muxc:NumberBox x:Name="nb1"
                        Header="صفحات" 
                        Value="604" Minimum="1" Maximum="604"
                        SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact"
                        SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10"                                                                      
                        Width="100"/>
    <Grid RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="nb1" Margin="0,24,30,0" Height="30" Background="#FF666666">
        <TextBlock Name="nb1MaxValue" Text="604" 
                   Foreground="White"
                   Padding="5,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</RelativePanel>
```

[image]

But why one number has an English format and the other a Persian format !!! O_O

Comment: You would need to create your own version of this control most likely why dont you take the sacrifice and just add a label somewhere displaying the maximum ? is there any reason you need to display it all?

Comment: I want to do this for the sake of beauty

Comment: then your best bet would be either inherint and overriding the control or building your user control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumberBox represents a control that can be used to display and edit numbers.

In your scenior, [Number formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.numberformatting?view=winrt-19041) can be used to format the value of a Numberbox, its result is still a number, not an expression such as 12/128.

I suggest that you could write a TextBlock to cover the NumberBox through [RelativePanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel?view=winrt-19041#border-properties) like following.

```
<Page
……
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid>
    <RelativePanel BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Padding="12">
        <muxc:NumberBox   x:Name="MyNumberBox"
            Header="Page" Value="15"
            Minimum="1" Maximum="128"
            SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact"
            SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10"                                                                      
            Width="150"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" d:IsHidden="True"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="/128" Margin="50,-30,0,0" RelativePanel.Below="MyNumberBox"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid> 
</Page>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this method helps me - I edited your code and I edited my first post